# How do I get the name of the constructor for a product type in purescript?? Similar to haskell conNameOf

Tags: purescript

I want to extract the value of the constructor for my data which is a sum of product types  `data X = Xa A | Xb B | Xcd C D | Xefg E F G....` , where A B C... are of the type `data A = A {a :: xyz , b :: abc..}`
I want a function that gets takes in a value of type X and gives me "Xa", "Xb" .. based on the type. I know I can use case but is there a better way to do this??  Haskell has the toConstr function for this purpose,

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a function in the standard library, but if you don't mind using the RTTI mechanisms (which is what `conNameOf` is using), you can relatively easily make your own using [`Generic`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.1/docs/Data.Generic.Rep#t:Generic): just convert the value to its generic representation using `from`, and then extract the constructor by matching on [`Sum`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.1/docs/Data.Generic.Rep#t:Sum) and [`Constructor`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.1/docs/Data.Generic.Rep#t:Constructor):

```
class ConstrName rep where
  constrName' :: rep -> String

instance IsSymbol name => ConstrName (Constructor name a) where
  constrName' (Constructor _) = reflectSymbol (Proxy :: Proxy name)

instance (ConstrName a, ConstrName b) => ConstrName (Sum a b) where
  constrName' (Inl a) = constrName' a
  constrName' (Inr b) = constrName' b

constrName :: forall a rep. Generic a rep => ConstrName rep => a -> String
constrName a = constrName' $ from a
```

Usage:

```
> constrName (Xa $ A { a: ..., b: ..., .... })
"Xa"
```